GDAL VSICurl URL for ESRI shapefiles generating incorrect URLs when URL has query parameters
I am trying to use GDAL's VSICurl to access data on a webserver. The URL for the data requires query parameters, for example:
https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two

This works in a web browser for downloading the data. Now I want to use this data in Mapserver which accepts a vsicurl path.
So my vsicurl path might look like:
/vsicurl/https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two

And in Python code:
from osgeo import gdal
path = '/vsicurl/https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two'
ds = gdal.Open(path)

This method works perfectly for single file formats e.g. geotiffs. However, for shapefiles, it looks like GDAL tries to create URLs for sidecar files that are not right, for example:
https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two.xml
https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two.shx
https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two.shp

Note the final ".xml"; the url should instead be:
https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.xml?first_value=one&second_value=two
https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shx?first_value=one&second_value=two
https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two

I see from the documentation that GDAL supports some query parameters for vsicurl type URLs, however, it does not allow arbitrary or custom query paramters as far as I can tell.
Is this a limitation of GDAL, have I misunderstood the documentation, or is there some workaround that I could use in my situation? I should point out that I am not in control of somesite in this scenario so I cannot change the way that it works.

"I see from the documentation that GDAL supports some query parameters for vsicurl..." - No, it supports setting various GDAL options, these are not URL query parameters. Other "VSI" Virtual File System types also use a "?" character to specify GDAL options.

What do you mean "This works in a web browser for downloading the data"? Do you get the shp, shx and dbf files in one request?

"This works in a web browser" - I mean that the url: https://www.somesite.com/files/someshapefile.shp?first_value=one&second_value=two is valid. I would still need to do separate requests for the sidecar files. Probably that information in my question was a bit superfluous

Is "somesite.com" one of the major cloud storage services?  If so, there may be a /vsi[cloud storage] virtual filesystem available instead. If not, can "somesite.com" handle the parameters as HTTP headers instead of url query parameters?

Yes, its in an Azure blob. However, I find that vsiaz is quite slow when being used by mapserver. vsicurl using an SAS token (which is a set of query parameters) for the same dataset and layer parameters (for a geotiff) works brilliantly. Our initial plan was to use mapserver's cloud optimised shapefiles. However, fortunately our requirements have changed.

From this Github feature request I raised the answer is that arbitrary query parameters are not supported by vsicurl due to how niche the requirement is.
